# SQLite query in Android Nougat is not backwards compatible

Tags: android, sqlite, android-7.0-nougat

I have an SQLite query that does *not* return a record by `_id` on Android Nougat but *does* return a record on Android pre-Nougat.

When I attach a debugger to the Nougat emulator and start poking around, I observe the following:

**Original Code**

```
readableDatabase.query("report_view", null, "_id = ?", new String[]{"2016309001"}, null, null, null).getCount()
```

Result: 0

**Poking around / Evaluate expression**

```
readableDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM report_view WHERE _id = 2016309001", null).getCount()
```

Result: 1

Enabling the SQLite log results in (note the single quotes):

```
V/SQLiteStatements: /data/user/0/xyz/bla.db: "SELECT * FROM report_view WHERE _id = '2016309001'"
```

For the *non-raw* query on Nougat. I cannot seem to enable the SQLite log on the pre-Nougat (Marshmallow) device.

So it seems the issue is caused by Android surrounding the parameter with single quotes. The `_id` column is of type `integer`. And a value surrounded by quotes is of type `string`. Why is this suddenly an issue on Nougat?

Comment: Just to be clear, the original code stopped working when a user upgraded from Marshmallow to Nougat.

Comment: it shouldn't matter http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/751bc/4 ... SQLite doesnt has great type control ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless I am mistaken your original code passes the date parameter explicitly as a string (new String[]), and the Android documentation for the query method, selectioArgs parameter states

> **selectionArgs** String: You may include ?s in selection, which will be
>   replaced by the values from selectionArgs, in order that they appear
>   in the selection. **The values will be bound as Strings**.

So if you want something else than strings, you should probably perform a cast, or better, do not use the query and rawQuery methods, but prepared statements ([SQLiteStatement](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteStatement.html)), which will allow you to specify the type of parameters.

Also the '?' being substituted in the log should be a "fake" substitution for logging purposes (at least I hope it is a fake substitution for logging purposes, as Android should be using a bound parameter there, and not replace it in the query).

Finally the field types in Android are used only for [type affinity](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html), so it is entirely possible that even if you declared your field as "integer" in the table, if you used the Query method and its String-only parameters, you actually ended up with strings in your records.

Comment: Although non of the answers answered the original question (Why is this suddenly an issue on Nougat?), I picked this one as the accepted because it provides a neat alternative (SQLiteStatement). I still think it's odd that the behaviour changed when a user upgraded from Marshmallow to Nougat...

Comment: The query/rawQuery API parameters relied on some sort of type guessing (in Java and/or in SQLite), which likely led to various scenarios which were subsequently reported as bugs. They should probably just have marked those methods as deprecated, the changes they made wil only lead to ping-pong'ing bugs between use cases.

Answer (score 0):

In theory, SQLite should not behave differently. It is possible that you are using a different table definition that results in a different [affinity](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#affinity).

Anyway, the parameter you give to the `query` function is a string, so it is not surprising that the database handles it as a string.

If you want to give a number to the database, you have to make the parameter a number.
And the Android framework doesn't allow this for most database functions, so you have to put it directly into the string:

```java
db.query("report_view", null, "_id = " + "2016309001", null, null, null, null).getCount();
```

Please note that there is a [helper function](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/DatabaseUtils.html#queryNumEntries(android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) for counting rows:

```java
DatabaseUtils.queryNumEntries(db, "report_view", "_id = " + "2016309001");
```